# Removing a smaller circle using imopen/imclose operation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary image with two circles of different radii and need to remove either of the circles using either an `imopen` or `imclose` operation. I have used the structuring element having the diameter greater than the smaller circle but less than the bigger circle but it doesn't seem to work for either operation.

My image:

[image]

My code:

```
c=imread('image.png');
se2=strel('disk',25);
c=imopen(c,se2);
figure, imshow(c,[]), title('new image');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see three things that will cause this algorithm not to run with the intended results:

1. Your image has the circles as black, but binary morphological operations assume that the objects are **white**.  As such, what you are actually doing is performing the operations on the background instead.  Therefore, you need to **invert** the image before you perform morphological operations on the image.
2. The `disk` structuring element is too small to remove any of the circles.  You need to bump up your radius so that it's more.  I did some tests and to get out the smaller circle, I had to bump up the radius to 45.
3. In addition, the `disk` structuring element that you specified is not a **perfect** circle.  In fact, it would be a slight diamond shape.  If you want to get a perfect circle, you need to specify an additional parameter to `strel` with the `disk` parameter which is `0` on top of the radius (`45`).  Once you do this, you invert the image back to where it was, as the objects were black and not white.

Therefore, your code should look like:

```
%// Modified to read from StackOverflow
c = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hd0y.png')); 
se = strel('disk', 45, 0); %// Change radius to 45 + add additional parameter of 0
c2 = imopen(~c, se); %// Invert the image before opening
c2 = ~c2; %// Invert back because original image was this way
imshow(c2); title('New Image');
```

This is the image I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### **[`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html)** + **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based solution

If you care for performance, let me suggest a  method based on `bwlabel` and the very powerful vectorization tool - `bsxfun` that might be better than using `image morphological operations`. Now, your problem is basically a biggest blob finding problem and here's the code -

```
c = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hd0y.png')); 
[L,num] = bwlabel( ~c );
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
[~,ind] = max(counts);
c = ~(L==ind);
```

---

### Benchmark

Benchmarking Code against `imopen` based method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25777914/3293881) -

```
c = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hd0y.png')); 

disp('----------------------------------- With IMOPEN')
tic
se = strel('disk', 45, 0); %// Change radius to 45 + add additional parameter of 0
c2 = imopen(~c, se); %// Invert the image before opening
c2 = ~c2; %// Invert back because original image was this way
toc

disp('----------------------------------- With BWLABEL + BSXFUN')
tic
[L,num] = bwlabel( ~c );
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
[~,ind] = max(counts);
out = ~(L==ind);
toc
```

Results -

```
----------------------------------- With IMOPEN
Elapsed time is 0.195290 seconds.
----------------------------------- With BWLABEL + BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 0.020950 seconds.
```

---

### Bonus analysis

Another reason why you might want to do away with morphological operations would be that `imopen` changes your blobs around the edges. You can visualize this, if you perform absolute difference between input and output images. So, if you do `figure,imshow(imabsdiff(c,c2))`, you would get this -

[image]

As you can see the bigger blob has changed around its edges. In a perfectly preserving case, only the smaller blob must be there.

Comment: Ah :) Very nice approach with `bsxfun` and `bwlabel`. The question did state that the OP needed to use `imopen` and `imclose`.  It sounds like a homework question, so I don't think there's any deviation in the requirements.  I'd personally choose this approach because there is no (or very little) morphology involved.  +1 btw.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Well yeah smelled like HW! And yeah `bsxfun` had to find its scope wherever possible :) You had my +1 already!